# Views attach not working in my theme

Tags: views

I can't seem to get views attach to work in the theme I've created... is there maybe a line of code I'm missing that needs to be included in page.tpl.php for it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you overridden any views templates in your theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can just do:

```
<?php
$viewName = 'WHATEVER';
print views_embed_view($viewName);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I use this rather than the 'Views Attach' module. Just a more flexible way to embed views IMO.